# How to sort a List of Objects in ascending order based on an enum using Java?

Tags: java, collections, enums

Lets say you have a particular enum called Field:

```
public enum Field {
    ALBUM,
    YEAR,
    DESCRIPTION
}
```

And you have a corresponding Java interface called Music

```
public interface Music {
    String getAlbum();
}
```

And you implement it like this:

```
public class MusicImpl implements Music {
    public String getAlbum() {
        return this.getField(Field.ALBUM)
    }

    @Override
    public Object getField(Field field) {
        Object myObject = field.getClass();
        return myObject;
    }
}
```

How can you sort it using the field:

```
public class MusicManager {
    public List<Music> sortAlbums(Field field, boolean ascending) {
        List<Music> albums = new ArrayList<Music>();
        Music music = new MusciImpl();
        if (ascending = true)
            albums.add(music);
            Collections.sort(albums);
        }
        return albums;
    }
}
```

Eclipse is throwing the following error at Collections.sort(albums):

```
Bound mismatch: The generic method sort(List<T>) of type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (List<Music>). The inferred type Music is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

Comment: Try to make a MusicComparator to define the rule of music sorting. Then use Collections.sort(albums, new MusicComparator());

Comment: What do you think your compare method is doing? Every time you are comparing same Field.ALBUM..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because "if you could provide me with a simple solution, I'd appreciate it" in response to answers illustrates that the OP is interested in neither learning nor adding to this site.

Comment: Also you completely changed your question. Don't do that. If you want to verify if code is correct, test it. I've reverted your edit to the original question so as not to invalidate answers below. If you have a new question, ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You would either need to implement Comparable on Music or you need to create a static class which would implement Comparable interface for your music class.

Make sure you have sort criteria already available. These mostly are based on data fields which is missing in your case. So in your case since you just have one enum field it doesn't makes sense to sort the list.

Answer (score 0):

Since the `Field` you are using as a sort key is determined at run time, your best option here is to use the version of [`Collections.sort`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) that takes a [`Comparator`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

Then you can create a `Comparator` that, given a `Field`, compares two `Music` objects based on the value of that field, and use that to sort the list, e.g.:

```
public class MusicFieldComparator implements Comparator<Music> { 

    private final Field field;

    public MusicFieldComparator (Field f) {
        field = f;
    }

    @Override  
    public int compare (Music m1, Music m2) {
        // ... return result based on `field` values, for example:
        switch (field) {
        case Field.ALBUM:
            return m1.getAlbum().compareTo(m2.getAlbum()); // not null-safe! up to you.
        // ... and so on, for other fields
        }
    }

}
```

Then e.g.:

```
Collections.sort(albums, new MusicFieldComparator(field));
```

You can add `ascending` as a field to your `MusicFieldComparator` in a similar way, and negate what `compare()` returns based on ascending vs. descending.

---

You'll note in the example above I have used `getAlbum()` directly. The reason I did that was, well, because I was tired and skipped right over your `Music.getField()`.

You *could* use `getField()` to potentially simplify `compare()`, however the caveats in order to truly take advantage of this are:

- You'll want to actually implement `getField()` correctly, returning `field.getClass()` is not what you want to do. I'll leave this as an exercise to you.
- You'll want to modify `getField()` to return a `Comparable` instead of an `Object`. More likely than not, however, especially if you're using basic type like `String` and `Integer` and such, this will involve nothing more than changing the return type, since all those types already implement `Comparable`.

So *assuming* `getField()` returns a `Comparable` and behaves correctly, the implementation becomes as simple as:

```
... 

@Override  
public int compare (Music m1, Music m2) {
    return m1.getField(field).compareTo(m2.getField(field)); // not null-safe!
}
```

As it stands, though, with your current non-working implementation of `getField()`, the above won't work as-is.

---

Also check out the [official tutorial on object ordering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/order.html), which is short, simple, and will give you a good basis to work from.

Comment: What would the compare method's implementation look like?

Comment: @AndrePerez I was hoping you'd learn something by working it out yourself! I have added a basic example. In general, see docs for `Comparator.compare`; returns negative if `m1 < m2`, 0 if equal, positive if `m1 > m2`, and you have full power to decide how to actually do those comparisons.

Comment: @AndrePerez And by the way; I completely ignored your `getField()`, which greatly simplifies `compare`. Sorry, it's late. I will update answer, although there are some caveats.

Comment: if you could provide me with a simple solution, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: @AndrePerez The above is a simple as it gets. Do your own work. You have everything you need and if you can't extend the example then go read some Java tutorials until you can. We made an effort to help you for free now make a minimal effort to help yourself. Don't be a [help vampire](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19665/the-help-vampire-problem), we don't want you here.